dotnet restore tries to restore something that it should not
I have a solution (.sln) containing a bunch of C# projects (.csproj) that I develop both in Visual Studio and in Visual Studio Code (for historical reasons; the older ones in VS, the newer ones in VSC). Last time I worked on them was Nov 2023, now in Apr 2024 I start again.
I can build all projects with no problems in VS. In Nov 2023 I could build them in VSC using dotnet build projectname with no problems.
Now in Apr 2024, when I try to build ANY of these projects in VSC using dotnet build projectname, I get the following error message:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.202\NuGet.targets(169,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xarial/xcad/_packaging/xcad-preview/nuget
/v3/index.json" [C:...\solutionfolder\projectname\projectname.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.202\NuGet.targets(169,5): error :
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found - The
feed with ID 'xcad-preview' d  oesn't exist. (DevOps Activity ID:
1CED97CE-D3E7-4898-9755-017D993B10FB)).
[C:...\solutionfolder\projectname\projectname.csproj]

I do not get that error message when I omit restoring (dotnet build projectname --no-restore).
None of the projects of the solution contains a reference to this xarial xcad nuget. I did play around with that nuget in the past, but not inside the solution in question. I had some playground projects loaded in my VSC workspace - besides the solution projects - and used it in there. So I assume there is some garbage file somewhere that tells nuget restore to try to restore the xcad nuget even though it is not listed in the projects themselves.
Note: I have never done anything with DevOps, I don't even know what this is.
Any ideas how I can get rid of that problem? Any file locations I can check and remove files from there? Any cleanup commands? ...?

It turns out that I had added the xarial xcad thing to my nuget.config at some point and did not remember that I had. The file is located in %appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config and there was the line
<add key="xCAD" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xarial/xcad/_packaging/xcad-preview/nuget/v3/index.json" />

inside <packageSources>. After removing it, I could use VSC again with no problems.
The only question that remains is: Why did it still work in VS, i.e. why did VS not consider nuget.config?
